# Execute anonymous unexpected token '<'

Tags: apex, execute-anonymous

I receive this error:

> Line: 5, Column: 4 unexpected token: '<'

When executing this code in the execute anonymous window in the developer console:

```
Map<String, List<Custom_Object__c>> idsToCustomObjectList = Map<String, List<Custom_Object__c>>();
```

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error is a little misleading. You are missing the `new` keyword when you assign `idsToCustomObjectList`.

```
Map<String, List<Custom_Object__c>> idsToCustomObjectList = new Map<String, List<Custom_Object__c>>();
```